# Please i need help on how to concatenate phone numbers and add +234 at the beginning and still separte with comma from the following one

Tags: php, implode

```
<?php
$phonenumber = 090254,090906,081343;

session_start();
$phonenumbers = $_SESSION['phonenumber'];

$arrayName = array($phonenumbers);
```

> so please how can i add +234 to phonenumbers been moved in to the next page and still separate the next one number from the other with a comma.

Comment: What is `$phonenumber` supposed to be? A string? Is that what is contained inside `$_SESSION['phonenumber']`? Your question is not clear. Also, have you tried anything? While we're glad to help when you're stuck, you're still expected to make an effort of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($arrayName as $key) {
    $user_status = explode(",", $key);
    //print_r($user_status);
}
$i = 1;
$total_phone_num = count($user_status);
$before_last = $total_phone_num - 1;

$valid_phone_num = "'";

foreach ( $user_status as $valid_phone){
 
if ($i <= $before_last){
$valid_phone_num = $valid_phone_num."+234".$valid_phone.",";
}else{

$valid_phone_num = $valid_phone_num."+234".$valid_phone."'";
}
$i = $i + 1;
}

echo $valid_phone_num;
```

I finally found an answer

> output '+23409025741418,+23409090806070,+2340808345525'

Comment: You could simplify your code a lot if you simply made an array of modified numbers and [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it instead of manually tracking where to place the comma.